# scheduled task or windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have to create an app that will read in some info from a db, process the data, write changes back to the db, and then send an email with these changes to some users or groups. I will be writing this in c#, and this process must be run once a week at a particular time.  This will be running on a Windows 2008 Server.

In the past, I would always go the route of creating a windows service with a timer and setting the time/day for it to be run in the app.config file so that it can be changed and only have to be restarted to catch the update.

Recently, though, I have seen blog posts and such that recommend writing a console application and then using a scheduled task to execute it.

I have read many posts talking to this very issue, but have not seen a definitive answer about which process is better.

What do any of you think?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it is a one per week application, why waste the resources for it to be running in the background for the rest of the week.

A console application seems much more appropriate.

The typical rule of thumb that I use is something along these lines.  First I ask a few questions.

1. Frequency of Execution
2. Frequency of changes to #1
3. Triggering Mechanism

Basically from here if the frequency of execution is daily or less frequent I'll almost always lean towards a scheduled task.   Then looking at the frequency for changes, if there is a high demand for schedule changes, I'll also try to lean towards scheduled tasks, to allow no-coding changes for schedule changes.  lastly if there is ever a thought of a trigger other than time, then I'll lean towards windows services to help "future proof" an application.  Say for example the requirement changes to be run every time a user drops a file in X folder.

Comment: I agree about using up the server resources. I think this is the direction I will go.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The basic rule I follow is: if you need to be running continuously because events of interest can happen at any time, use a service (or daemon in UNIX).

If you just want to periodically do something, use a scheduled task (or `cron`).

The clincher here is your phrase `"must be run once a week at a particular time"` - go for a scheduled task.

Comment: That's what I thought.  As I had been reading through posts, that was the feeling I got towards doing this.  i will give it a try.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have only one application and you need it to run once a week may be scheduler will be good as there is no need to have separate service and process running on the system which will be idle most of the time.